# C# Use int constants vs Enums without cast

Tags: c#, enums

I have some int constants grouped in several Enum, like:

```
enum myEnum{ 
OBJECT_A = 10, OBJECT_B = 13 };
```

Now I have several functions which take this Enums and do something, like:

```
void myfunc(myEnum e)
{ .... }
```

In my code, I need to use myfunc in both these two ways:

```
myfunc(myEnum.OBJECT_A);
myfunc(13);
```

This gives an error because ints aren't casted to Enum implicitly.

**What do you recommend as a best practice to do this preserving readability of the code?**

An obvious solution is to use myfunc((myEnum)13); but this is boring because one needs to cast the int every time and the code gets heavy.

So far what I did is (avoiding enums at all):

```
using EChannelInt = System.Int32;

public static class EChannel
{
    public static readonly int CH_CONNECTION        = 10;
    public static readonly int CH_DATA              = 50;
}

public void doit(EChannelInt ch)
{ .... }

doit(EChannel.CH_DATA);
doit(10);
```

which works, but I don't like it very much because it seems like a "trick" or renaming thigs. What do you suggest? Perhaps "implicit operator" may be useful?

Comment: Clarification from the spec: `int` usually cannot converted implicitly to an enum type, *with the exception of the numeric literal `0`*.

Comment: "In my code, I need to" -- No, you don't need to: it's very clearly possible to disallow `myfunc(13)` without any loss of functionality: the caller could write `myfunc((myEnum)13)` instead. You *want* to. That's something else. Why do you want to? Perhaps understanding your reasoning for that can get you a better approach.

Comment: Passing `13` around your code reduces the readability and makes the code more prone to errors. Cast 13 to `myEnum.OBJECT_B` at the earliest opportunity and use `myEnum.OBJECT_B` throughout the rest of the code. Creating lots of overloaded functions or allowing ints to be implicitly cast to enums will create code that's less easy to read and far harder to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can overload `myFunc`:

```
void myFunc(int i)
{
    myFunc((myEnum)i);
}
```

Comment: That's what I did for a similar case, and it works very well. However, some validation was added to ensure compatibilty between the passed int and the enum values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [type-safe-enum](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html) pattern and you can override the implicit cast operator.

```
public class EChannel
{
    public int Value {get; private set;};

    public static readonly EChannel CH_CONNECTION        = new EChannel(10);
    public static readonly EChannel CH_DATA              = new EChannel(50);

    private EChannel(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator EChannel(int a)
    {
        EChannel eChannel = null;
        switch (a) // this need to be changed to something more light
        {
            case 10:
                eChannel = CH_CONNECTION;
                break;
            case 50:
                eChannel = CH_DATA;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Constant don't exists");
        }
        return eChannel;
    }
}
```

And you use it like this

```
public void doit(EChannel ch)
{ .... }

doit(EChannel.CH_DATA);
doit(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an overload?

```
void myfunc(int i)
{
    myfunc((myEnum)i);
}
```

(If you don't have control of the class, you can do it as an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx).)

Comment: that's true, but since these functions are a lot, I'd have to overload every one of them just to deal with enums... so I get two copy of each function... is it readable in this way?

Comment: @edoedoedo I think it's readable, yes. If you have a lot of them, maybe you should make *all* the `int` versions extension methods, so they're grouped away from the main content of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with the enumeration values as much as possible and only cast to `int` in a narrow scope when absolutely necessary (if at all).

However, if you insist on mixing integers and enumeration values then you should consider defining the `enum` members from the integers so that they are guaranteed to be consistent.

Example:

```
public static class EChannel
{
    public const int CH_CONNECTION = 10;
}

public enum myEnum
{
    CH_CONNECTION = EChannel.CH_CONNECTION
}
```